# Keras Sequential Model Training Sample Less Than Input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use Keras to train a CNN to classify images of dogs and cats. The problem is as I run model.fit() the actual training samples are way less than my input. There are more than 19000 images in my input and the process bar only shows 562. On the bottom left you can see 562/562. I realized this because I have significantly lower accuracy than the tutorial.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUFL1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn about `batch_size`.
From the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model), `fit` will  `batch_size will default to 32`,

so `19000/32 = 593`, which is close to the 562, I'm guess you used some samples for validation

To be a bit more exact, you used 17984 (562 * 32) samples for training and I assume 1998 (0.1% of the total, ~19982) samples for validation.